# Duplicates data in Select Option Loop - SQL : VBScript

Tags: sql

Im trying to remove the duplicates data which occurs :

**Events & Hall**
Banquet Table
**Events & Hall**
Mic Stand
**Co-Curriculum**
Traffic Cone
**Landscape**
Vase
**Sports**
Ball

But the output i want is :

**Events & Hall**
Banquet Table
Mic Stand
**Co-Curriculum**
Traffic Cone
**Landscape**
Vase
**Sports**
Ball

Here are the codes :

```
<select name="s_item" style="width:173px;" onChange="Retrieve(this.value)" required>
    <option value="">Select Item</option>
    <%
    SET rsItem = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsItem.Open "SELECT * FROM inv_general",conn                                    

    IF rsItem.EOF <> true then
    DO WHILE rsItem.EOF <> true


    SET rsCat = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsCat.Open "SELECT * FROM inv_category WHERE inv_cat_id='"&rsItem("inv_cat_id")&"'",conn
    %>
    <optgroup label="<%=rsCat("inv_cat_name")%>">
    <option value="<%=rsItem("inv_item_id")%>"<%IF request("item")=rsItem("inv_item_id") THEN%>selected<%END IF%>><%=rsItem("inv_item_name")%></option>
    </optgroup>
    <% 
    rsItem.MOVENEXT
    LOOP
    END IF %>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which dbms you're using but try the following code and lets see it works out for you.

```
<select name="s_item" style="width:173px;" onChange="Retrieve(this.value)" required>
    <option value="">Select Item</option>
    <%

    Dim parentName
    parentName = ""

    SET rsItem = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsItem.Open "SELECT c.inv_cat_name, i.inv_item_id, i.inv_item_name FROM inv_general i INNER JOIN inv_category c on i.inv_cat_id = c.inv_cat_id order by c.inv_cat_name, i.inv_item_name",conn                                    

    IF rsItem.EOF <> true then
    DO WHILE rsItem.EOF <> true
    If parentName <> rsCat("inv_cat_name") Then
    parentName = rsCat("inv_cat_name")
    %>
    <optgroup label="<%=parentName%>">
    <%
    End If
    %>
    <option value="<%=rsItem("inv_item_id")%>"<%IF request("item")=rsItem("inv_item_id") THEN%>selected<%END IF%>><%=rsItem("inv_item_name")%></option>
    </optgroup>
    <% 
    rsItem.MOVENEXT
    LOOP
    END IF %>
    </select>
```

You don't need to execute an extra SQL statement if you join your item and category tables like this:

```
SELECT c.inv_cat_name, i.inv_item_id, inv_item_name FROM inv_general i INNER JOIN inv_category c on i.inv_cat_id = c.inv_cat_id order by c.inv_cat_name, inv_item_name
```

then you need to store the category name in a temp variable which is `parentName`. Since you order the results by category name and item name, by using

```
If parentName <> rsCat("inv_cat_name") Then

End If
```

block, you basically avoid duplicate category names. The code may have syntax errors, I don't have a chance to test it right now. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much Ozgur Bar!!!!It works!! love u bro!!! btw, im using MySQL DB. Sorry about that :D